# Issue with reading input in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I wrote a program that uses inbuilt stack API in java.

```
    Stack <Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    int n = in.nextInt(); // number of instructions
    in.nextLine(); // code to consume \n left out after nextInt()
    String str="";
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        str = in.nextLine(); // Instructions for operations. Ex: 1) + 20 (pushes 20 to stack) 2) - (pops item)
        char ch = str.charAt(0);
        if(ch=='+')
            stack.add(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1).trim()));
        else 
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
    System.out.println(str); //statement that I wrote to debug
```

This works fine if I enter input line by line i.e first entering the number of instructions, next each instruction in one line. But if I paste a set of input lines and press enter then this code is reading one extra line input.

To be clear let me explain this with the example I tried:

```
    input text:
    6
    + 1
    + 10
    -
    + 2
    + 1234
    -
```

the expected output is:

```
    10
    1234
```

But the program is waiting to read input after printing 10 so the output looks like:

```
    10
    //waiting for input now if I enter some text let's say test and hit enter, then it's printing 1234.
    1234
```

I wrote the last println statement to test whether or not I am reading input and the String str is printing -test

Can someone please explain why this behavior is occurring?

Comment: Because your loop executes 6 times? So after the 10, you must continue? Unclear ...

Answer (score 0):

The nextLine() method of java.util.Scanner class advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This function prints the rest of the current line, leaving out the line separator at the end.

If you are trying to paste a set of instructions, after each line of the set try to add "\n", otherwise it may think that the entire set of instructions is just one single line.

You can also do some testing of how the lines are perceived by using the hasNextLine() method.

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout my code. Here, you can directly paste set of input all together and it will work fine:

```
public static void stackExample() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    String str = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        str = br.readLine();

        //This is for handling, if there is any extra newline or a space in input
        if (str.isEmpty() || str.equals(" ")) {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        if (str.charAt(0) == '+') {
            stack.add(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1).trim()));
        } else {
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
        }
    }
}
```